# C# Selenium Chrome choose one from many Certificates

Tags: c#, selenium, ssl-certificate

I have seen a few questions posted on various mediums about this but nothing with a working C# example that I have been able to implement. So, I have a C# project that is using Selenium. I am calling the ChromeDriver as follows:

```
        using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://MySecureWebApplication/");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }
```

which launches a Chrome browser as would be expected. I am then prompted with a 'Select a Certificate' dialogue:

[image: Certificate Popup]

I need to find a way to be able to automate the selection of the CORRECT certificate. That is, there can be a number of different certificates listed in the popup and in code I need to be able to somehow set a pointer to the correct one.

Comment: Here is a list of options.  Not sure which to use : https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I found that the easiest way was to use the Chrome Policies in the Windows Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"="{"pattern":"https://MySecureWebApplication","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"IssuerCN"}}}"
```

Where you replace your address and the IssuerCN as your certificates IssuerCN value.

Comment: you can also skip all of them using this : {"pattern":"[*.]","filter":{}}